# Related Links for Content

Tags: 7, users

In the design for my article pages I have related links in a right hand side column.

In Drupal administration when you edit content I want to have a 'Related Links' section, which prints a list of the content currently on the site with checkboxes so a user can choose which pages should be displayed as related.

I'm new to Drupal development, however have experience in working with PHP/mySQL and writing modules for other content management systems.

What steps should I go about to achieve this? And how would I then print the selection on the front-end of the site?

Thanks so much for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [References](http://drupal.org/project/references) or [Entity References](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference) (recommended) module, you can add node reference fields to your node type. 
It's pretty straight forwad. I'd suggest looking at drupal.org docs about making node types asyou are new to Drupal. You will not need to code anything in most cases. for content display, you can use theme templates and/or [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views).